# How can I factory reset my Raspberry Pi 4 model B?

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, chromium

I got my Raspberry Pi 4 yesterday and have already managed to uninstall the browser. I don't want to go through the kerfuffle of reinstalling everything that I deleted and since I haven't done much on it, I was wondering if there was a factory reset shortcut?

Comment: As far as I know, the Raspberry Pi doesn't have an SD card installed when it comes out of the factory.  So if all you have done is uninstalling the browser, removing the SD card will factory reset it.

Answer (score 18):

All the configuration is on the SD card.

There is no factory reset option.

You will have to reflash the SD card to get back to the original position.

Comment: "All the configuration is on the SD card." - except the configuration in the EEPROM.

Comment: If he has a kit that came with NOOBS, that’s a fairly painless way to revert to “factory settings.”

Comment: @PeteHooper - if he has NOOBS, he's in a world of pain from the start :p

Answer (score 10):

Welcome to the world of Raspberry Pi! Fortunately, the operating system on a Raspberry Pi is typically Linux based, and I assume this is the same for you. If I am understanding your question correctly, then you want to reinstall a browser onto your Raspberry Pi without having to reflash the whole OS. If so, just run:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

In a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in Ubuntu or just navigate to terminal through the desktop. You will probably have to type

```
y
```

in response to the install request, but other than that, you should be good to go in a few seconds!

Comment: You can avoid the need to type `y` if you use the `-y` option.

Comment: @Ruslan yeah thats a fair point. I kind of wanted to aim this at the simplest possible command without flags so that the command was reasonably understandble as it sounds like OP doesn't have any experience interacting with the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If you got one of the Raspberry Pi kits that come with the SD card with NOOBS (CanaKit is the most popular one), you can hold shift as the Pi is booting to be taken to the NOOBS install screen. At that point you can pick whatever version you want to install.

That being said, if you flashed the SD card yourself, you will have to go through the trouble of re-flashing the SD card with the OS version you originally installed (as others have pointed out).